# How to clean the parsing output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a Python Crash Course exercise and tried to experiment with BeautifulSoup.
I tried some things and couldn't find a solution so I'm asking here what to do.

So how do I get rid of the first output, that's not a burger name? 
And how do I get rid of the \n and .?

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us/full-menu/burgers.html').text

soup = bs(source, 'html.parser')

sandwiches_ordered = []
finished_sandwiches =[]

for menu in soup.find_all('div', id='maincatcontent'):
    for burger in soup.find_all('div', class_='categories-item-details'):
        sandwiches_ordered.append(burger.text)

print("We are making all the sandwiches!\n")

while sandwiches_ordered:
    sandwich = sandwiches_ordered.pop()
    finished_sandwiches.append(sandwich)

for sandwich in finished_sandwiches:
    print(f"Here is your {sandwich}.")
```

And my output is:

```
We are making all the sandwiches!

Here is your 
#{itemName}

                      #{nutrientValue}

.
Here is your 
Hamburger
.
Here is your 
Double Cheeseburger
.
Here is your 
Cheeseburger
.
Here is your 
Quarter Pounder®* with Cheese Bacon
.
Here is your 
McDouble®
.
Here is your 
Quarter Pounder®* with Cheese Deluxe
.
Here is your 
Double Quarter Pounder®* with Cheese
.
Here is your 
Quarter Pounder®* with Cheese
.
Here is your 
Little Mac™
.
Here is your 
Double Big Mac®
.
Here is your 
Big Mac®
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `replace()` function to get rid of the newline characters and slice the list (`finished_sandwiches[1:]`) to get rid of the first output which is not a burger name. I have included the code below that incorperates the two fixes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us/full-menu/burgers.html').text

soup = bs(source, 'html.parser')

sandwiches_ordered = []
finished_sandwiches =[]

for menu in soup.find_all('div', id='maincatcontent'):
    for burger in soup.find_all('div', class_='categories-item-details'):
        sandwiches_ordered.append(burger.text)

print("We are making all the sandwiches!\n")

while sandwiches_ordered:
    sandwich = sandwiches_ordered.pop()
    finished_sandwiches.append(sandwich.replace("\n", ""))

for sandwich in finished_sandwiches[1:]:
    print(f"Here is your {sandwich}.")
```